# Mysql 3 table join and update

Tags: mysql, date, join

I am attempting to join 3 tables and update some values based on the data in the tables.

The table and columns affected are:

**users**

id | user_registered

**members**

user_id | status

**user_meta**

user_id | key | value

I basically want to get all users from the users table that registered more than 7 days ago by the user_registered column and then join their id with the user_id of the members table where the status is active and then join them with the user_id of the user_meta table where the key is = to 'capability' and the value is = to pending. And then finally update the value to active.

I had the following but I don't think it's correct as it is not grouping the records together and not joining and I'm not sure of the correct syntax:

```
SELECT u.id, u.user_registered, p.user_id, p.status, um.user_id, um.key, um.value
FROM users u, members p, user_meta um
WHERE u.user_registered < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND p.status = "active" AND um.key='capability' AND value='pending'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: is there ant error you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update user_meta table based on your logic in two ways.

Query 1:

```
UPDATE user_meta
SET user_meta.value = 'active'
WHERE user_meta.user_id IN
(SELECT id
    FROM (SELECT u.id
        FROM users u JOIN members p ON (u.id = p.user_id)
                             JOIN user_meta um ON (u.id = um.user_id)
                WHERE u.user_registered < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
                                     AND p.status = "active"
                                     AND um.key = 'capability'
                                     AND um.value = 'pending'
             )tmp)
```

Query 2:

```
UPDATE user_meta
  JOIN (SELECT u.id
        FROM users u
          JOIN members p ON (u.id = p.user_id)
          JOIN user_meta um ON (u.id = um.user_id)
        WHERE u.user_registered < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
            AND p.status = "active"
            AND um.key = 'capability'
            AND um.value = 'pending') tmp
    ON (tmp.id = user_meta.user_id)
SET user_meta.value = 'active'
```

The Query 1 will take long time if the number of select query row is large and column is not properly indexed as it use **IN** statement.

Comment: Hi thanks for your time on this! It Almost works perfectly except I didn't want it to set the entire value column to active. only the rows that had a key of capability. Any further help would be awesome but if not thanks for this! :D

Comment: Actually it's ok actually I fixed it by updating the set part and adding a where. Thanks for your help!